# .htaccess subfolder rewrite, add trailing slash without escaping '%'

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm attempting to host my website's primary domain from a subfolder of its document root - yielding a directory structure like:

```
/public_html/www.main-domain.com/ <--I need to do this with htaccess
/public_html/sub1.main-domain.com/ <--For subdomains I can just set the doc root w/ cpanel
/public_html/sub2.main-domain.com/
```

It's shared hosting (HostGator), so I don't have the ability to use virtual hosts.  This situation has solutions posted all over the web ([1](http://chanon.info/change-main-domain-to-subfolder/399/), [2](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347), etc), consisting of htaccess rules like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main\-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www.main\-domain.com/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.main-domain.com/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?main\-domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ www.main-domain.com/index.php [L]
```

The above rules do work, except if I try to access any subfolder of www.main-domain.com *without a trailing slash*.  For instance, if I visit the url

```
http://www.main-domain.com/images/ (with trailing slash)
```

it works fine.  However, if I visit

```
http://www.main-domain.com/images (no trailing slash)
```

then the browser URL bar changes to show the actual, full server path:

```
http://www.main-domain.com/www.main-domain.com/images/
```

Note that in both cases, the *content* is served correctly - the only issue is that (unless a trailing slash is explicitly entered) the URL bar will change to reveal the 'true' server directory structure, rather than just the desired "www.main-domain.com/images."

This is effectively the same question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2992901/host-primary-domain-from-a-subfolder), however the accepted answer is to use virtual hosts - which isn't possible in my case.  The same person also posted on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/a/149019/343621), but that's been closed to replies.  The one promising answer there suggests adding the following before the final index.php rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/$
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1/
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work for me.  If someone could suggest a set of rules that accomplishes the 'primary domain in a subfolder,' *and* which doesn't suffer from the "no-trailing-slash" issue, I'd be very grateful.

--**Edit**--

I've got this mostly working via the following rules:

```
# Externally redirect to add trailing slash to extensionless URLs if missing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Internally rewrite all requests to subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.example.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This works, except with URLs like:

```
http://www.example.com/my-script?xdm_e=https%3A%2F%2Fjk.test
```

Which gets redirected to:

```
http://www.example.com/my-script/?xdm_e=https%253A%252F%252Fjk.test
```

Note that in addition to adding the trailing slash (as desired), percent symbols have also been expanded to "%25". I thought this might have something to do with the "B" flag, but adding that to the RewriteRule just made things worse ("my-script" got changed to "my%252dscript", and the latter percents were still altered).

Again I am stumped...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was as simple as adding the "NE" flag.  My final working rules are therefore:

```
# Externally redirect to add trailing slash to extensionless URLs if missing
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]+/)*[^./]+)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,NE,R=301]

# Internally rewrite all requests to subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /www.example.com/$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```